# Get property to other task from another task groovy/gradle

Tags: android, properties, groovy, gradle

I have got the following task in project B :

```
1111 {
 def revision = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
 exec{
 executable "/bin/sh"
 args "-c", "echo -n git rev-list HEAD | wc -l | sed 's/^[ ^t]*//'"
 standardOutput = revision;
 println "$revision"
}

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def apkName = "${group}";
        apkName += "-${version}";
        if (!variant.zipAlign) {
            apkName += "-unaligned";
        }
        apkName +=  "-$revision";
        apkName += "-" + defaultConfig.versionName;
        apkName += "-" + variant.buildType.name;
        apkName += ".apk";
        println  apkName;
        variant.outputFile = file("$project.buildDir/apk/" + apkName)
    }
 }
```

I have to create another task in project B, and have to get properties from task 1111: apkName, revision, defaultConfig.versionName. I can get just defaultConfig.versionName, like

```
println 1111.defaultConfig.versionName
```

how to get the properties apkName and revision?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle catch the task result to output property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503458/gradle-catch-the-task-result-to-output-property)

Comment: but nothing work( and i'am still looking for decision

Comment: [May be of interest](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_pass_objects_from_one_gradle_task_to_another)